# Short story where a teenager can kill with his mind

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, telekinesis

I remember reading this sci-fi short story where a boy had the ability to kill people with his mind.  He would try very hard never to get angry, because once he did, he would think something along the lines of "I wish he/she would die".  I remember part of the story happened on a bus.  Does anyone know the name?

Comment: I agree the questions are duplicates.  However, I think the other question should be closed instead because mine was already answered correctly by Kyle more than 5 years ago.  Would it help if update my question to include the details about the ending (meeting his cult family)?  I would credit TriNebula for that part, since I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the story you're referring to is ["Eye for Eye"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_for_Eye) by Orson Scott Card.  From Wikipedia:

> Mick Winger has an unusual gift and with it has accidentally killed several people. When Mick gets angry at people, his power manifests itself by launching an attack upon them by giving them cancer, leukemia or related terminal illnesses. If made angry enough, his anger can outright kill the victim.

There was a scene early in the story where Mick, despite his best efforts, ends up zapping a bus driver with his power.  Excerpt:

> Some other people said, "Hey!" kind of mad, and I realize now that they was saying it to the driver, cause they was on my side. But at the time I thought they was mad at me, and that plus the scare of nearly falling and how mad I already was, well, I lost control of myself. I could just feel it in me, like sparklers in my blood veins, spinning around my whole body and then throwing off this pulse that went and hit that bus driver. He was behind me, so I didn't see it with my eyes. But I could feel that sparkiness connect up with him, and twist him around inside, and then finally it came loose from me, I didn't feel it no more. I wasn't mad no more. But I knew I'd done him already.

Comment: @red.october -  Do you remember something about him seeing 'Sparks' flow out from him and over people he got angry at?  Or him being captured by 'his' people who wanted to breed him to maintain their 'power'? Those are also elements of this story.

Comment: Whoa, that was fast.  Yep, that's the one!  I did google it with Card's name, but I guess it's difficult to search.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a bit like *It's a Good Life* by Jerome Bixby.

Wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Good_Life)

The story concerns a three-year old boy, not a teenager and I don't recall a bus. However, the other themes are similar. The story takes place in a village which has somehow separated itself from the rest of the Earth at the moment of the boy's birth. It was adapted as an episode of The Twilight Zone ([Wiki page here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Good_Life_%28The_Twilight_Zone%29)).

---

[Edit]
Probably a bit pointless as another answer has appeared which looks like a better match, but just to clarify the age of the child (Anthony) in *It's a Good Life*. In the story, Anthony is three, not six. Perhaps there is a confusion with the Twilight Zone episode in which (I believe) Anthony is six. Here is a quote from the story (form *Star Fourteen* edited by Frederik Pohl, although it appears in many other anthologies):

> It did no good to wonder where they were ... no good at all. Peaksville was just someplace.
>   Someplace away from the world. It was wherever it had been since that day three years ago
>   when Anthony had crept from her womb and old Doc Bates - God rest him - had screamed and
>   dropped him and tried to kill him, and Anthony had whined and done the thing. He had taken
>   the village someplace. Or had destroyed the world and left only the village, nobody knew which.

You can find the full text online (although I'm not sure of the legality).

Comment: It was a good thing they adapted that story into a Twilight Zone episode... it was a *very good thing they did*.

Comment: I considered that answer too, but the part in the question about him trying not to get angry made me think it wasn't it.  That kid was pure evil.

Comment: @Chelonian - Anthony is three in the original story (answer edited to clarify). Perhaps you are thinking of the Twilight Zone?

Comment: @Fruitbat Yes, I was thinking about Twilight Zone. I'll delete my erroneous comment. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the main character in my story is definitely not evil like this little boy :)